# Hide c3js lines on spline graphe

Tags: c3

On c3js spine graph is it possible to hide the line using the API? I know I could use a scatter graph instead, but I got to use spline with my requirements.

Also, setting the opacity of .c3-lines.c3-line to 0 is hiding it, but I want to know if I can achieve it through the API

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hide it using the API. See http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-hide. Samples from the documentation.

> ```
> // data1 will be hidden.
> chart.hide('data1');
>
> // data1 and data2 will be hidden.
> chart.hide(['data1', 'data2']);
>
> // all targets will be hidden.
> chart.hide();
>
> // data1 will be hidden together with its legend.
> chart.hide('data1', {withLegend: true});
> ```

Comment: But this is hiding everything including the data points. I want show the data points but hide the lines connecting them

Comment: In that case it is basically styling and CSS (static or script inserted) would be right way to go about it. 

I don't see any API method to do it, but I could have just missed something. Any reason why you need an API method?

Comment: I have taken the CSS route too, I thought it will be cleaner to do it with the API. Thank you!